# Proving a jigsaw is possible

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

This is an offshoot of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2313084/how-to-prove-if-an-n-size-jigsaw-puzzle-is-solvable).

Suppose we have jigsaw puzzle pieces which are basically squares but where each side can be either straight, concave or convex. An example of three such pieces is shown below:
[image]

It is clear that there can be $3^4=81$ different types of pieces. I was wondering, given one of each type (and with no rotations or flips allowed), whether it was possible to create a standard jigsaw puzzle, using just those $81$ pieces. By "standard jigsaw puzzle" I mean one of dimensions $m \times n$ where all perimeter sides are straight.

A $1\times 81$ puzzle is clearly not possible as it would require all $81$ pieces to be straight on both the left and the right side. A similar argument holds for a $81\times 1$ puzzle.

A $3\times 27$ puzzle would require $27$ pieces with a left straight side and $27$ pieces with a right straight edge, and while it is true that such two sets exist, they have an overlap of $9$ pieces. This is therefore not possible. As before, a similar argument holds for a $27\times 3$ puzzle.

This leaves the $9\times 9$ possibility. A priori, I can see no reason this shouldn't be possible. And I think I have a proof that it is possible, which is what I would like your opinion on.

Given a $9\times 9$ puzzle, we have the situation below:
[image]

Each black side of a piece is fixed, but each green side of a piece represents a possible connection type. A connection type could be a "straight - straight", "concave - convex" or "convex - concave" type. It seems to me that if we run through every possible connection type for each piece, one of those scenarios must give a puzzle where each of the $81$ piece types is used exactly once.

Am I right?

Comment: "if we run through every possible connection type for each piece" - I'm not sure I understand what you mean. What about the piece with all straight sides, the one with all concave sides, and the one with all convex sides? Could you clarify your statement?

Comment: @Michael Lee: All connection types would be tried for all connections, including the ones you mention (as long as they are not on the border).

Comment: What you're describing sounds like a brute-force method of generating a solution if one exists, but definitely not a proof of existence.

Comment: @Michael Lee: I am not suggesting an algorithm. I'm basically asking if there is a reason that trying all possible connections should not result in a puzzle consisting only of the $81$ types.

Comment: If there is such a solution, you'll find it.  If there isn't, you won't.  I see no reason to rule out either possibility.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Could you explain why trying every possible connection type would not necessarily result in the conclusion I make?

Comment: It won't if there isn't a solution.

Comment: @Jens; Robert Israel is saying that while the approach you're suggesting is a valid strategy to find out if there is a solution or not, it is not in itself a proof either way. You could end up trying every single combination and find that none of them actually make a valid grid (though in this particular case, as Bram28 answered, it is in fact possible and therefore brute-force will indeed find a solution when applied). As a silly example of the negative, I could claim a boolean "a" exists such that "a = not a", with the "proof" that if I try every possible value of a, one of them must work.

Comment: The "content" of such is essentially that what you wrote is not an existence proof. It's a method of finding a solution, if one exists, but it's obviously possible to modify the puzzle in such a way that the method you described would not generate a solution, such as in the $3\times 27$ case.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I wouldn't call what you say a proof ... It is not immediately clear from what you say that you will indeed get all possible pieces in there.

However, your hunch is correct: this puzzle is indeed solvable. Here is a proof:

Let's call the straight edge $1$, the concave edge $2$, and the convex edge $3$. Now, label the $10$ vertical edges in each row of your $9 \times 9$ board with $1,1,2,3,1,3,3,2,2,1$ in that order.  Note that if you look at two sucessive edges (so these would be the left and right edges of a piece), you get all possible pairings: $11,12,23,31,13,33,32,22,21$. Hence, pieces in the same column will have the same left and right edge, but pieces in different columns will have differen left/right pairings.

Ok, do the same with the horizontal edges from top to bottom. This will give you all possible pairings for top and bottom edges. So, since different rows have different top/bottom pairings, and since different columns will have different left/right pairings, you do indeed get all $81$ possible combinations, and thus all the $81$ different pieces in there.

Here is the resulting solved puzzle (thanks @Frxstrem !)

[image]

Comment: I'm convinced. Thank you.

Comment: @Jens You're welcome! :) I was playing with those 1,2,3's for a while, and initally had a hard time (which is why it wasn't at all clear to me there had to be a solution) ... But then I found the right way to think about it, and just had to find a sequence with all possible pairings

Comment: By the way, this is a [de Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of order 2 on an alphabet of size 3.

Comment: @Rahul huh!  Didn't know about them ... Cool, thanks!! :)

Comment: @Bram28 Here's an illustration of your solution, if you want to add it to your answer: https://imgur.com/a/H78uk

Comment: Is this answer unique (up to reflections/rotations) or are there several options for coding each axis?

Comment: @Frxstrem Cool, thanks!  I added it to my post.

Comment: @Neil_UK Ignoring the 11,22, and 33, there are different ways to do the  the 'core' sequence:, e.g. mine was 123132, but you can also have 231213 and 312321 (and those can be mirrored of course). And now you have to double one of the 1's, one of the 2's and one of the 3's, which can be done in different ways. So even with rotations and reflections there are still  various solutions.

Comment: Really elegant, I like your solution!

Comment: @flawr Thanks! :)

Comment: Wow! Thank you @Bram28 and Frxstrem. I did not expect an actual example of a solution. Isn't MSE great? :)

Comment: @Jens I agree! Thanks for the problem! :)

Comment: The symmetry is interesting.  Are the other solutions similarly symmetric?

Comment: @Polyergic For the ones I mention in the comment above, yes.  But JeanMarie noted in a comment to her own post that you can interchange chunks to get different solutions yet, and you'll quickly lose symmetry,

Comment: @Bram28 If you have some time, have a look at the little Edit I have written in my solution.

Answer (score 14):

This answer, complementing the excellent answer of @Bram28, explains the idea with line coloring. It is possible (see figure 1) to place 10 horizontal and 10 vertical lines using (R,G,B) colors in such a way that the $3^4=81$ different squares are present (for example, there is a unique square with North, West, South, East colored (G,B,R,R) resp.: this square is found in the South East corner). Check that the $3^4=81$ different squares are present once and only once.

Now, attribute colors to each side according to its shape:

- R$\to$"flat side",
- G$\to$"convex side",
- B$\to$"concave side".

This gives figure 2.

**Remarks:**

1) The color sequencing of lines and columns has been chosen different in a deliberate way. In fact there are 24 different color sequencements. Why that ? Identify East and West side of the board ; similarly, identify the North and South sides ; said otherwise, consider our puzzle as drawn on a torus, so  $9 \times 9$ is the number of pieces and as well the number of lines. This number $9$ is, I would say by chance, a power $9=3^2$, allowing to use the framework of **de Bruijn sequences** here of type $B(3,2)$. Such  a sequence is made of $3^2$ "letters" (imagined arranged in a ring) such that, by sliding a window of width 2 on the sequence, one gets all the words on an alphabet of 3 items : R,G,B. An example : RRGGBBRBG where the window sliding will provide RR,RG,GG,GB,BB,BR,RB,BG and GR, all the words with 2 letters on an alphabet of 3 (please note that the last word, GR, has been obtained by wrapping the sequence). For more, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) where you will find a formula explaining that there are $6^3/3^2=24$ of them.

2) Out of a solution, one can generally build a big amount of other solutions. For example, in the case of the given figure, consider the two identical $1 \times 4$ (or $1 \times 5$, or $3 \times 3$... !) rectangles in the South West and North East corners of the puzzle : another solution is provided by switching them.

[image]

[image]

---

**Edit :** (Feb 8 '18)

Related :

http://erikdemaine.org/papers/Jigsaw_GC/paper.pdf

[What is known about this jigsaw combinatorics problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/619053)

Somewhat related :

https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48864

I found an old reference mentionning an analogous type of pieces in an old-fashioned delicious booklet entitled "New Mathematical Pastimes" by Major McMahon, Cambridge, 1921 
 (https://archive.org/details/newmathematicalp00macmuoft) (page 69) .

Comment: Cool, thanks!! Yes, that's a nice illustration :)

Comment: Based on the OP's 1x81 and 3x27 proofs, I think that the intention is for all outside edges of the 9x9 puzzle to be straight.  Your solution would fit that criteria if the top three rows were removed from the top to the bottom of the puzzle.

Comment: @James You are right. I am going to modify my example.

Comment: While it's not triggering the flickering dots of the [classic B&W version (halfway down)](https://www.sciencealert.com/here-s-why-you-can-t-see-all-12-black-dots-in-this-crazy-optical-illusion), your colored grid of lines is throwing me for a mental loop.  My subconscious is insisting that something should be going on there even though nothing's making its way up to my conscious sight.

Comment: @Dan Neely I have modified my figures, but the effect should still be present. On the "subconscient" side, this set of 81 pieces could take place on a cylinder (by gluing the two vertical sides) or even a torus (by gluing as well the two horizontal sides).

Comment: Thank you for your example. I'm now wondering how many solutions actually exist.

Comment: Out of a  solution like mine, you can build others. Consider for example the two horizontal 1 x 4 rectangles in the South West and North East part of the puzzle : they are interchangeable and are different, yielding another solution. I think that we can do that again and again giving a hugo number of solutions...

Comment: @Jens A curious correspondence with the alternating sign matrices  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_sign_matrix). Is it a track towards the answer to your question ?